# NEO4J Rest API: Create or update

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j 1.8.2. My nodes have a property that I used as an identifier. Is possible update the other properties if a node with that identifier exists or create it otherwise using only one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should index that property and use the index to search for the node and create if not present or update otherwise. See the doc [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html)

It would require two requests though, I'm not sure you can do it only with one using the REST API. You'd probably need to write your extension or plugin [(doc here)](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-extending.html) and perhaps use the
[pessimistic locking](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html) if you really need a single request.